# Getting multiple items out of this.router.events.subscribe()

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am currently subscribing on router events to change the title of my page when routes change, like so

```
this.routerSub$ = this.router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
    .map(route => {
        while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
        return route;
    })
    .filter(route => route.outlet === 'primary')
    .mergeMap(route => route.data)
    .subscribe((event) => {
        title = event['title']
            ? `${event['title']}`
            : 'Default Title'
        this.title.setTitle(title);
    });
```

My issue is that on certain scenarios, I want to set the title to a value in url (part of a route). How do I do this here? I know I cannot subscribe to the url as well as events but am having a hard time figuring out what to map inside.

**Here is what I am trying that is failing**

```
   this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .map(() => {
            return this.activatedRoute
        })
      .switchMap(route => {
        return route.data.combineLatest(route.url, (data, url) => {
            return data['title'] ? `Title: ${data['title']}` : url.join('');
        });
    })
```

On the .switchMap line, route is of type ActivatedRoute, route.data is of type Object and the error I get on the combineLatest() line is

> route.data.combineLatest is not a function

Comment: Do you mean that you want to observe both `events` and `url` and somehow combine their values? If so, `combineLatest` or `withLatestFrom` could help.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me the right way. So I basically create an any object and assign events and url as props to it? Maybe a small sample would help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we leave aside angular routing details, you basically want to combine values from two different streams. There's at least a couple of ways how to do that.

**Case 1**. You want to update the title whenever either of the streams emits and use the most recent values from both.

Use [`combineLatest`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html):

```js
const getTitle$ = (activatedRoute) => {
    return activatedRoute.url
        .combineLatest(activatedRoute.data, (url, data) => {
            return url + data;
        });
};

const url = Rx.Observable.interval(400).take(3).map(x => `url_${x} `);
const data = Rx.Observable.interval(200).take(6).map(x => `data_${x}`);

getTitle$({ url, data }).subscribe(title => console.log(title));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

**Case 2**. You want to update the title only when the `url` stream emits, but also get the most recent value from the `data` stream.

Use [`withLatestFrom`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/withlatestfrom.html):

```js
const getTitle$ = (activatedRoute) => {
    return activatedRoute.url
        .withLatestFrom(activatedRoute.data, (url, data) => {
            return url + data;
        });
}

const url = Rx.Observable.interval(400).take(3).map(x => `url_${x} `);
const data = Rx.Observable.interval(200).take(6).map(x => `data_${x}`);

getTitle$({ url, data }).subscribe(title => console.log(title));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>
```

If you encounter that your observable does not contain any of these operators, try to import them explicitly:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/combineLatest';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/withLatestFrom';
```

**Update:**

To make it more specific, here's a code sample that is closer to your original example:

```
this.router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ... // <- route mapping and filtering skipped for brevity
    .switchMap(route => {
        return route.data.combineLatest(route.url, (data, url) => {
            // make the title out of data and url
            return data['title'] ? `Title: ${data['title']}` : url.join('');
        });
    })
    .subscribe(title => this.title.setTitle(title));
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I am still a little lost. I need to get multiple properties (data and url) from this.activatedRoute in some manner. I am trying to incorporate combineLatest in that chain and am getting Type Errors. Do I need create a const for data and a const for url, and merge them?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what type errors you get and how your code looks like? `data` and `url` of the `ActivatedRoute` both seem to be observables, but with different element types. You can combine those values the way you need in the projection function you pass to `combineLatest`, i.e. signature would look something like `combineLatest(Observable<UrlSegment[]>, Observable<Data>, (UrlSegment[], Data) => String)`.

Comment: I updated the answer with two more code samples which I tried to make more specific.

Comment: getting an error saying route.data.combineLatest is not a function. It looks like route.data is already resolved so you cannot perform Observable functions on it.

Comment: I wonder, how could that be? In your original example there's a line `.mergeMap(route => route.data)`, so for that code to work `route.data` has to be either `Observable`, or an `Array`, or a `Promise`. [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#data) say that it *is* an observable. Or could that `route` be of type `AngularRouteShanshot`? Could you check the types? BTW, if the `data` is indeed resolved, then it's even easier, you don't have to combine streams, just use that `data`.

Comment: Oh, that's weird, cause that contradicts to what [the docs say](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#data). And how did you manage to do `.mergeMap(route => route.data)` if `route.data` is an `Object`? Is it so that `route.url` is also not an `Observable`, but just a `UrlSegment[]`? BTW, will it work if you try just `this.activatedRoute.url.combineLatest(this.activatedRoute.data).subscribe(urlAndData => console.log(urlAndData))`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150434/discussion-between-isaac-levin-and-sergey-karavaev).